# Xamarin.iOS CoreBluetooth/External Accesory issue

Tags: ios, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've looking here on Forums, on the monotouch samples GIT hub, and never found a really functional sample to use CoreBluetooth in order to achieve the following:
1.Check if is there a device that match a criteria(by name or some identifier of the device) paired and connected
2.If paired but not connected, try connect to it
3.If connection fails, then show a list of the bluetooth devices that matches the criterias on topic 1 so the user can select and connect to it

Note: The device I'm trying to connect uses SPP but is Apple MFi certified. It is a credit card reader over bluetooth and some of then even implement ExternalAccessory protocols

The CoreBluetooth samples page is empty http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/ios/CoreBluetooth/

I've trying this pretty simple sample that never get the events called after the scan:

```
public static class BTHelper
    {
        private static CBCentralManager manager;
        private static CBUUID UUID;

        static BTHelper()
        {
            manager =
            manager.DiscoveredPeripheral += OnDiscovery;
            manager.ConnectedPeripheral += OnConnected;
            manager.DisconnectedPeripheral += OnDisconnected;
            UUID = CBUUID.FromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
        }

        public static void CheckBluetooth()
        {
            manager.ScanForPeripherals(new[] { UUID });
        }

        static void OnDisconnected(object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected - " + e.Peripheral.Name);
        }

        static void OnConnected(object sender, CBPeripheralEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected - " + e.Peripheral.Name);
        }

        static void OnDiscovery(object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found - " + e.Peripheral.Name);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help? I've being really tired of googling and looking of many questions on SO with no real answer.

@XamarinTeam, you guys should provide a sample on how to use it... We are lost without reference...

Thank, really appreciate any help...

Gutemberg

Comment: iOS does not support SPP.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but, the BT device passed Apple MFi license program and does implement ExternalAccessory protocol. I have it working pretty fine on native objetive-C\

Comment: If it is MFi and SPP then Core-Bluetooth isn't what you are after - it is the external accessory framework

Comment: Already tried external accessory but, no success in find any docs or samples. If you can provide one that helps accomplish the 3 points I posted I appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin examples, but you need to know the external accessory identifier for your peripheral and put this in your plist. CoreBluetooth singly for accessing GATT Bt 4.0 profile

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884195/externalaccessory-on-ios-at-xamarin

Comment: Guys, I know how to use the ExternalAccessories... If you look at its API, its for CONNECTED accessories... Check my questions... I need 1. check if it is connected, 2. search for in range device, 3. connect. After that than I'll use EAxxx classes for access the device...

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are looking at wrong documents.Core Bluetooth only allows you to communicate with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices using the GATT profile. you can not scan SPP device with corebluetooth.

For your MFI device, you need to check  External Accessory framework ,  It  allows communication with 'legacy' Bluetooth devices using profiles such as the Serial Port Protocol (SPP).

To answer your question:
: 1.Check if is there a device that match a criteria(by name or some identifier of the device) paired and connected

> > You can use `showBluetoothAccessoryPicker` function of `EAAccessoryManager`  to get list of Available devices, read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613913-showbluetoothaccessorypicker)

2.If paired but not connected, try connect to it

> > There is not any documented way to check for this. You can not initiate connect from app without `showBluetoothAccessoryPicker` . You can monitor for 
> >     [EAAccessoryDidConnect](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1613827-eaaccessorydidconnect)  notification. if this method is not called, and showbluetoothaccessorypicker 's complition get called, your device is not connected.

3.If connection fails, then show a list of the bluetooth devices that matches the criterias on topic 1 so the user can select and connect to it
1)

> > After completion of  `showbluetoothaccessorypicker`  You can check in `ConnectedAccessories` . If its not avaiable, call `showbluetoothaccessorypicker` to display list of accessories.

Sample code for using External Accessory framework in your code

```
EAAccessoryManager manager= EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager;
var allaccessorries= manager.ConnectedAccessories;
foreach(var accessory in allaccessorries)
{
    yourlable.Text = "find accessory";
    Console.WriteLine(accessory.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(accessory.Name);
    var protocol = "com.Yourprotocol.name";

    if(accessory.ProtocolStrings.Where(s => s == protocol).Any())
    {
        yourlable.Text = "Accessory  found";
        //start session
        var session = new EASession(accessory, protocol);
        var outputStream = session.OutputStream;
        outputStream.Delegate = new MyOutputStreamDelegate(yourlable);
        outputStream.Schedule(NSRunLoop.Current, "kCFRunLoopDefaultMode");
        outputStream.Open();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyOutputStreamDelegate : NSStreamDelegate
{
    UILabel label;
    bool hasWritten = false;

    public MyOutputStreamDelegate(UILabel label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public override void HandleEvent(NSStream theStream, NSStreamEvent streamEvent)
    {
         //write code to handle  stream.

    }
}
```

There is not any perticular demo for using Exeternal  Accessory  framework,
but You can check this sample code for understanding how it works.:

[Whole Project](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios9/HomeKitCatalog)

[AccessoryBrowser class](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios9/HomeKitCatalog/HomeKitCatalog/ViewControllers/Accessories/AccessoryBrowserViewController.cs)